# Rotate keyboard 90 degree in ios using CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios7, rotation, orientation, cgaffinetransform

This is my code,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( DEGREES_RADIANS(90));            
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(+90.0, +90.0 );
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, landscapeTransform);
```

I just wanted to rotate the my UIview which is under UInavigation controller and it contains number of textviews and textfields.Used the above code I could transform my current view to landscape mode but I worried for a long that when I click textfield the keyborad always shows the portrait mode. I need to transform the keyboard to landscape mode using CGAffineTransform as well. I really appreciate if anyone assist me.

Comment: Why do you rotate manually instead of using the orientations settings?

Comment: @shaikriyaz, when retagging, please *always* carefully select tags from the autocomplete.  You accidentally created a new tag where one already existed.

Comment: @Charles I just replicated the tag while copying the code sorry about that. All I want to do is UIViewcontrollers to be in portrait mode except the one I need in my app. How do I control a single view controller to be in landscape mode.. Can you post a sample code snippet? that would be helpful. Thanks in advance.